# How to detect when website can’t be reached from popup.js with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have some code in my popup from my extension that depends on the content of the tab's current website, but I should be able to detect when the website don't exists (like in the image below) so when the user opens the popup in an invalid website I can show some message like "Extension won't work here because website don't exists"

[Example of unreachable website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2iwH.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API to check the `errorOccurred` field:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
  chrome.webNavigation.getFrame({tabId: tabs[0].id, frameId: 0}, frame => {
    if (frame.errorOccurred) {
      document.body.textContent = 'ERROR';
    }
  });
});
```

You'll also need `"permissions": ["webNavigation"]` in manifest.json.

---

#### An alternative solution

Use `"permissions": ["activeTab"]` and test by injection:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: '1'}, ([ok] = []) => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !ok) {
    document.body.textContent = 'ERROR';
  }
});
```